# Should I use "or" or "and" in negative questions?

Tags: grammar, usage, conjunctions

When a sentence is in the negative form and the speaker wants to list several things, "or" should be used. For example,

> She doesn't like math or languages. (She doesn't like math. And she doesn't like languages.)

> I don't want a car or a bike. (I don't want a car. And I don't want a bike.)

---

How about negative questions? Should I use "and" or "or"?

I want to imply that: He is immune to a cough. And he is also immune to a fever.

> Isn't he immune to a cough **and/or** a fever?

I want to imply that: She is interested in math. And she is also interested in languages.

> Isn't she interested in math **and/or** languages?

Comment: Are you trying to say perhaps "She doesn't like math or foreign languages"?. Yours sounds bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these two cases use "and". But I would recommend adding "both" to them to emphasise that the initial words apply to two items. Thus making: *"Isn't he immune to both a cough and a fever?"* and *"Isn't she interested in both maths and languages?"*. (For UK English I would use "maths" not "math".)